# Combing scatterplots on Vegalite

Tags: charts, vega-lite

I'm trying to combine 3 scatterplots to look something like this
[image: Example]
the code for the example

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "repeat": {
    "row": ["Horsepower", "Acceleration", "Miles_per_Gallon"],
    "column": ["Miles_per_Gallon", "Acceleration", "Horsepower"]
  },
  "spec": {
    "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
    "mark": "point",
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "brush",
        "select": {
          "type": "interval",
          "resolve": "union",
          "on": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "translate": "[mousedown[event.shiftKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "zoom": "wheel![event.shiftKey]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "grid",
        "select": {
          "type": "interval",
          "resolve": "global",
          "translate": "[mousedown[!event.shiftKey], window:mouseup] > window:mousemove!",
          "zoom": "wheel![!event.shiftKey]"
        },
        "bind": "scales"
      }
    ],
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"field": {"repeat": "column"}, "type": "quantitative"},
      "y": {
        "field": {"repeat": "row"},
        "type": "quantitative",
        "axis": {"minExtent": 30}
      },
      "color": {
        "condition": {
          "param": "brush",
          "field": "Origin",
          "type": "nominal"
        },
        "value": "grey"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I have 3 separate scatterplots that all you the same data set. After numerous attempts I still can't figure out how to put them together / link them. I know mine is a little more complicated because my axis aren't the same.
I've really been struggling with this, any help would be GREATLY appreciated as I need it for uni. Thank you!

[image: my charts]

chart 1

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Number of Billionaires and Education Attainment",
    "subtitle": "From 2015-2020. Sources: Forbes & World Bank",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "height": 100,
  "width": 100,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/correlation.csv"
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.Educationalattainment/100", "as": "percent"},
    {"filter": {"field": "Educationalattainment", "gt": 0}}
  ],
  "selection": {
    "paintbrush": {"type": "multi", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true},
    "grid": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5, "color": "#C96E11"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Number of Billionaires",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "title": "Number of Billionaires",
        "grid": false,
        "tickCount": 10
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "percent",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "Educational Attainment", "grid": false, "format": "%"}
    },
    "size": {
      "condition": {
        "selection": "paintbrush",
        "value": 300,
        "init": {"value": 70}
      },
      "value": 70
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Year", "type": "nominal", "title": "Year"},
      {"field": "Country", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Country"},
      {
        "field": "Number of Billionaires",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": "No of Billionaires"
      },
      {
        "field": "Educationalattainment",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": "Educational attainment at least completed short-cycle tertiary population 25+ total (%) (cumulative)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

chart 2

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "GDP per capita and Education Attainment",
    "subtitle": "From 2015-2020. Sources: World Bank",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "height": 100,
  "width": 100,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/correlation.csv"
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.Educationalattainment/100", "as": "percent"},
    {"filter": {"field": "Educationalattainment", "gt": 0}}
  ],
  "selection": {
    "paintbrush": {"type": "multi", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true},
    "grid": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5, "color": "#EC9D3E"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "GDP per capita",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "title": "GDP per capita",
        "grid": false,
        "tickCount": 10,
        "labelOverlap": "greedy"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "percent",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "Educational Attainment", "grid": false, "format": "%"}
    },
    "size": {
      "condition": {
        "selection": "paintbrush",
        "value": 300,
        "init": {"value": 70}
      },
      "value": 70
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Year", "type": "nominal", "title": "Year"},
      {"field": "Country", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Country"},
      {"field": "GDP per capita", "type": "nominal", "title": "GDP per capita"},
      {
        "field": "Educationalattainment",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": "Educational attainment at least completed short-cycle tertiary population 25+ total (%) (cumulative)"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

chart 3

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "No of billionaires and GDP per capita",
    "subtitle": "From 2015-2020. Sources: Forbes & World Bank",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "height": 100,
  "width": 100,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/correlation.csv"
  },
  "selection": {
    "paintbrush": {"type": "multi", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true},
    "grid": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
  },
  "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5, "color": "#FBCA8B"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "Number of Billionaires",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {
        "title": "Number of Billionaires",
        "grid": false,
        "tickCount": 14
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "GDP per capita",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "GDP per capita", "grid": false}
    },
    "size": {
      "condition": {
        "selection": "paintbrush",
        "value": 300,
        "init": {"value": 70}
      },
      "value": 70
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Year", "type": "nominal", "title": "Year"},
      {"field": "Country", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Country"},
      {"field": "GDP per capita", "type": "nominal", "title": "GDP per capita"},
      {
        "field": "Number of Billionaires",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": "Number of Billionaires"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using repeat you can simply use `hconcat` to show your scatter charts side by side. Refer [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/concat.html#hconcat)

Below is the modified config or refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Nq8s0WZiKsxkwSSP0NBVh4+fzkGZRoDlGOFVA3FB0ko2EW9ws0AVKCUlI9no70ABiADCAE4AGz+IpFa0geKPHwksgnW0J0XTddAjBMcwrFsBwnE1Vx3DNJQqwVABHBhvFSDVSBNbQaDNLctn0CDTEsGx7EcZwtTcFd-WHNBrFWZFkJoT5HzqBJMxDJR5hAgkwJAC0Gj9bdxxAdDMJWFQcLOPCCM0VQFQ9DUXEESIfViEShzTBimLgJQRTMZBAxAABSVckgOI4pTkf8Cy3ZE1HzTVzWLUtyzGadBAYI4AGYsyUEk6CdLyfLQAB2YN+VCo5Iv5TA2CeFQcBjZ1+IXEAAE0u3bUSFVkHISRnFi0gVbLbmtW10v0diGASMxeOQnd9Daf8tRBEqlhAWr6t4n4qtdDKSKg8jYKohDaLy-QCvxdqxiI8C2Ggii4JcGizX6tLBvdIJPXgjldU0zimrEmaio65RFJ29UvTUnUYn1TAvCetRTSerEcDULQ-AgGA2kwfgoHmA84AsB0VFueYLBwY85RU2R8hKABqMG2BuNSAApTIASgsDHZVrDkaFIbG+VDbjYzgeNE2OAKQFTdMK1p7NHLzezQCLEkSzLX7RzEwn6yPeR0AQZs4Fbcwxk7btrjQPsfMHejCOaicHS82d5yuaUV24kB103TQVYefdDxAY8PjoXig0va8nheEB738F8ABFfP8b9fzYNrAK3YCt1AjKAHFnYABWhqCQhwFZ5qNiSEik4n1Fk-DKyu9Bg7DoSLEj6O6J01BGMEZjLrYjjAxOJR3lMQQAHk23eFL0CHOA4B8Pr+StgaBKExpjqm9A46w6Sk5AJA5NT0rrr21T1MOx6xm0hdC+LwzjP0czdYgKynVROyXIc3NnMbdBOYSdzeaUGK0H87MgsDUAr9QOLotWMKn+DZDEsEZLUoD-RytyihaahU5qdTKjlSqW0BI9T7I1fuZszBtWKpdSe6AYENUgX-dOodw6WBzjcGOp0QHIIWiADOuDs5ICjgQzaWCQDKVuvdX0fcgHoDOqAlBXUGH7WenPdEz0LCvWuNnHIn04DfQsL9f6gNgZqDBuYCGDVoawyJuEPIyNUbozxjjPGBM4bD1JmGCmGAqYJnLnTBmGZmZJEPuzQSbkeZM0NvzOsNAGzCz1mLCWuVpaIV7P2RW+dnEKi5uYdWSg5y+C1suDaa5bgG3gXuBoptzanitheK8Dw7Z3gdhkOwj4IgAA47Ae1JF7ACQE+LbXAsYUiy0xrwXWoQtCGF443GHrhFOhE06GFqSNGClFGmIQXkrZe+kS7DBgUmMQutO5QKDjgrO+CUAnRaZJdpidOnyU4QqchSyqG5xAIvXSRcBz8i3ocHetk6D71AKzI+HjT7cw8pfV+fk6Z3xCm8iKUVXneVih-ZQX8f6oElPM-+EDVnANmiQnpADMHVTQWXDBUL0CtXOvNHp6C+o2nBdgzOEcDkENRSAdhsLUFkMWYS6hKBaGIt6ZBMiAzVrUWGSSslF1SHDSZStcaTSjFGKAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "title": {
    "text": "Number of Billionaires and Education Attainment",
    "subtitle": "From 2015-2020. Sources: Forbes & World Bank",
    "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
    "subtitleFontSize": 10,
    "anchor": "start",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamieprince/jamieprince.github.io/main/correlation.csv"
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.Educationalattainment/100", "as": "percent"},
    {"filter": {"field": "Educationalattainment", "gt": 0}}
  ],
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "height": 100,
      "width": 100,
      "selection": {
        "paintbrush": {"type": "multi", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true},
        "grid": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
      },
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5, "color": "#C96E11"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Number of Billionaires",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Number of Billionaires",
            "grid": false,
            "tickCount": 10
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "percent",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Educational Attainment",
            "grid": false,
            "format": "%"
          }
        },
        "size": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "paintbrush",
            "value": 300,
            "init": {"value": 70}
          },
          "value": 70
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "Year", "type": "nominal", "title": "Year"},
          {"field": "Country", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Country"},
          {
            "field": "Number of Billionaires",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "No of Billionaires"
          },
          {
            "field": "Educationalattainment",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "Educational attainment at least completed short-cycle tertiary population 25+ total (%) (cumulative)"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "height": 100,
      "width": 100,
      "selection": {
        "paintbrush": {"type": "multi", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true},
        "grid": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
      },
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5, "color": "#EC9D3E"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "GDP per capita",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": "GDP per capita",
            "grid": false,
            "tickCount": 10,
            "labelOverlap": "greedy"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "percent",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Educational Attainment",
            "grid": false,
            "format": "%"
          }
        },
        "size": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "paintbrush",
            "value": 300,
            "init": {"value": 70}
          },
          "value": 70
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "Year", "type": "nominal", "title": "Year"},
          {"field": "Country", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Country"},
          {
            "field": "GDP per capita",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "GDP per capita"
          },
          {
            "field": "Educationalattainment",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "Educational attainment at least completed short-cycle tertiary population 25+ total (%) (cumulative)"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "height": 100,
      "width": 100,
      "selection": {
        "paintbrush": {"type": "multi", "on": "mouseover", "nearest": true},
        "grid": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}
      },
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "opacity": 0.5, "color": "#FBCA8B"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Number of Billionaires",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Number of Billionaires",
            "grid": false,
            "tickCount": 14
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "GDP per capita",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "GDP per capita", "grid": false}
        },
        "size": {
          "condition": {
            "selection": "paintbrush",
            "value": 300,
            "init": {"value": 70}
          },
          "value": 70
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "Year", "type": "nominal", "title": "Year"},
          {"field": "Country", "type": "ordinal", "title": "Country"},
          {
            "field": "GDP per capita",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "GDP per capita"
          },
          {
            "field": "Number of Billionaires",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "Number of Billionaires"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```